# App gives SIGBART and claims that index of array does not exist when opening a specific view, then crashes

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Everyone,

First time posting here, but here goes nothing. I'm currently contributing to an app I'm working on for school. The recent addition I've been working on is the planner function of the app. Yesterday, the app was able to create, move around, store, and delete assignments. Today, my goal was to add the ability to edit your assignments. When I tried running the new code for the first time, it returned a SIGBART error in addition to saying that the index I was trying to access in my array did not exist, even though I'm almost positive it does. Here's the entirety of the code:

https://github.com/nicholaszana/SSA-Mobile-App-PlannerTab

but I'm pretty sure that the error is in this ViewController:

```
//
//  NewAssignmentViewController.swift
//  PlannerTab
//
//  Created by Nicholas Zana on 9/21/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Nicholas Zana. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class NewAssignmentViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var assignmentTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var notesTextView: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var classPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dueDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
    var array:Array = [C1Name, C2Name, C3Name, C4Name, C5Name, C6Name]
    var selectedClassName = C1Name
    var dueDate:Date = Date()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.assignmentTextField.delegate = self
        notesTextView.delegate = self

        var namesArray:Array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentNamesArray")!
        var dueDateArray:Array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentDueDateArray")!
        var classArray:Array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentClassArray")!
        var notesArray:Array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentNotesArray")!
        notesTextView.text = notesArray[clickedCell] as! String
        assignmentTextField.text = namesArray[clickedCell] as! String
        dueDatePicker.date = dueDateArray[clickedCell] as! Date
        classPicker.selectRow(1, inComponent: 1, animated: false)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //clickedCell defined in other view controller
    @IBAction func didPressFinish(_ sender: Any) {
        var namesArray:Array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentNamesArray")!
        namesArray[clickedCell - 1] = "\(assignmentTextField.text!)"
        UserDefaults.standard.set(namesArray, forKey: "AssignmentNamesArray")
        var dueDateArray:Array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentDueDateArray")!
        dueDateArray[clickedCell - 1] = dueDate
        UserDefaults.standard.set(dueDateArray, forKey: "AssignmentDueDateArray")
        var classArray:Array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentClassArray")!
        classArray[clickedCell - 1] = selectedClassName
        UserDefaults.standard.set(classArray, forKey: "AssignmentClassArray")
        var notesArray:Array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentNotesArray")!
        notesArray[clickedCell - 1] = notesTextView.text!
        UserDefaults.standard.set(notesArray, forKey: "AssignmentNotesArray")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return array[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        selectedClassName = array[row]
    }


    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if(text == "\n") {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    @IBAction func dueDateValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        dueDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
        let selectedDate = dueDatePicker.date
        dueDate = selectedDate
    }



}
```

What's causing these errors? Are they separate issues, or one in the same?

Thanks,

/nzana

EDIT: Here is ViewController.swift:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  PlannerTab
//
//  Created by Nicholas Zana on 9/21/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Nicholas Zana. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

let C1Name = "History"

let C2Name = "Chemistry"

let C3Name = "Chinese 2A"

let C4Name = "Math II"

let C5Name = "Computer"

let C6Name = "Free"

var clickedCell:Int = 0

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIButton!
    //Outlet for Table View
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //Checks if App has ever been run before.
        if (UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "HasLaunchedOnce")) {
            // This code will be run only if the app has been run before.
        } else {
            //This code is only run on the very first app launch.
            //UserDefaults are just permanately stored (even after app closed) variables. Google Them. They're really cool and easy to use.

            //Stores "UserDefaults" to say that the App has launched before.
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "HasLaunchedOnce")
            //Updates UserDefaults
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            //Creates an Array in "UserDefaults" to store names of each task
            UserDefaults.standard.set(["This is your digital planner!", "Add assignments with +", "Swipe left to complete"],  forKey: "AssignmentNamesArray")
            //Creates an Array in "UserDefaults" to store the due date of each task
            UserDefaults.standard.set([Date(), Date(), Date()], forKey: "AssignmentDueDateArray")
            //Creates an Array in "UserDefaults" to store the due Period of each task
            UserDefaults.standard.set(["These are Notes. You can add additional information about an assignemnt here.","Notes","Notes"], forKey: "AssignmentNotesArray")
            //Creates an Array in "UserDefaults" to store the class of each task
            UserDefaults.standard.set([C1Name, C2Name, C3Name], forKey: "AssignmentClassArray")
        }
    }


        @IBAction func didPressPlus(_ sender: Any) {
            var namesArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentNamesArray")!
            namesArray.append("Assignment Name")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(namesArray, forKey: "AssignmentNamesArray")
            var dueDateArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentDueDateArray")!
            dueDateArray.append(Date())
            UserDefaults.standard.set(dueDateArray, forKey: "AssignmentDueDateArray")
            print(UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentDueDateArray")!)
            var classArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentClassArray")!
            classArray.append(C1Name)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(classArray, forKey: "AssignmentClassArray")
            var notesArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentNotesArray")!
            notesArray.append("Notes")
            clickedCell = namesArray.count
        }

    //Tells how many cells need to be in the table view
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentNamesArray")!.count
    }
    //Adds ability to delete cells
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
            var namesArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentNamesArray")!
            namesArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(namesArray, forKey: "AssignmentNamesArray")
            var dueDateArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentDueDateArray")!
            dueDateArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(dueDateArray, forKey: "AssignmentDueDateArray")
            print(UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentDueDateArray")!)
            var classArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentClassArray")!
            classArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(classArray, forKey: "AssignmentClassArray")
            var notesArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentNotesArray")!
            notesArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(namesArray, forKey: "AssignmentNotesArray")
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
            }
    }

    //Creates Cells
    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            //Creates a cell as defined by prototype cell
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AssignmentTableViewCellViewController
            //sets cell
        //Names
        let namesArray:Array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentNamesArray")!
        cell.assignmentNameLabel.text = namesArray[indexPath.row] as? String
        //Due Date
        func inputDateWeekdayAsString(Date:Date) -> String {
            let inputDate = Date

            let inputWeekday:Int = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: inputDate)

            let weekdayArray:Array = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
            if inputWeekday == nil {
                return "Error!"
            } else {
                return weekdayArray[inputWeekday - 1]
            }
        }
        let dueDateArray:Array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentDueDateArray")!
        DateFormatter().dateStyle = .long
        DateFormatter().locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_GB")
        let inputDate:Date = dueDateArray[indexPath.row] as! Date
        let inputDateForDisplay = DateFormatter().string(from: inputDate)
        let inputWeekdayAsStringVar = inputDateWeekdayAsString(Date: inputDate)
        let inputYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: inputDate)
        let inputMonth = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: inputDate)
        let inputDay = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: inputDate)
        let todayYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
        let todayMonth = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date())
        let todayDay = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: Date())
        var dueDateOutputString = "\(dueDateArray[indexPath.row])"

        if inputYear != todayYear {
            dueDateOutputString = "\(inputWeekdayAsStringVar), \(inputDateForDisplay)"
        } else if inputMonth != todayMonth {
            dueDateOutputString = "\(inputWeekdayAsStringVar), \(inputDateForDisplay)"
        } else if (inputDay - todayDay < 7) && (inputDay - todayDay > 0) {
            if inputDay - todayDay == 1 {
                dueDateOutputString = "Tommorow"
            } else {
            dueDateOutputString = "Next \(inputWeekdayAsStringVar)"
            }
        } else if (inputDay - todayDay > -7) && (inputDay - todayDay < 0) {
            if inputDay - todayDay == 1 {
                dueDateOutputString = "Yesterday"
            } else {
                dueDateOutputString = "Last \(inputWeekdayAsStringVar)"
            }
        } else if inputDay == todayDay {
            dueDateOutputString = "Today"
        } else {
           dueDateOutputString = "\(inputWeekdayAsStringVar), \(inputDateForDisplay)"
            print(inputDateForDisplay)
        }


        cell.assignmentDueDateLabel.text = dueDateOutputString
       //Class
        let assignmentClassArray:Array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentClassArray")!
        cell.assignmentClassLabel.text = assignmentClassArray[indexPath.row] as? String

        return (cell)
            }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 75;//Sets height of each Assignment Cell
    }

    //Allows dragging around cell order

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    //Tells app how to reorder arrays when table view is changed
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        //Names
        var namesArray:Array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentNamesArray")!
        let namesItem = namesArray[sourceIndexPath.row]
        namesArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        namesArray.insert(namesItem, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(namesArray, forKey: "AssignmentNamesArray")
        //DueDates
        var dueDateArray:Array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentDueDateArray")!
        let dueDateItem = dueDateArray[sourceIndexPath.row]
        dueDateArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        dueDateArray.insert(dueDateItem, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(dueDateArray, forKey: "AssignmentDueDateArray")
        //Class
        var classArray:Array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentClassArray")!
        let classItem = classArray[sourceIndexPath.row]
        classArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        classArray.insert(classItem, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(classArray, forKey: "AssignmentClassArray")
        //Notes
        var notesArray:Array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AssignmentNotesArray")!
        let notesItem = namesArray[sourceIndexPath.row]
        notesArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        notesArray.insert(notesItem, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(notesArray, forKey: "AssignmentNotesArray")
        //Synchronizes UserDefaults
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
    @IBAction func didPressEditButton(_ sender: Any) {
            //Enables dragging around items
             tableView.isEditing = !tableView.isEditing

        if tableView.isEditing == true {
            editButton.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
        } else {
            editButton.setTitle("Edit", for: .normal)
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        clickedCell = indexPath.row
    }

    }
```

As per request of "rt", here is the result of typing "bt" in the console. I'm not really sure what this means, though.

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x000000010fd67d42 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x000000010fd9f457 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 90
    frame #2: 0x000000010fa28107 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
    frame #3: 0x000000010f7ba91f libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 245
    frame #4: 0x000000010f7baabb libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 265
    frame #5: 0x000000010ae6c1be libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 97
    frame #6: 0x000000010f7d6159 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
    frame #7: 0x000000010f7d5e0a libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 99
    frame #8: 0x000000010ae6c0dc libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 40
    frame #9: 0x000000010b48fb09 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 537
    frame #10: 0x0000000110f829c6 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 62
    frame #11: 0x000000010b983d30 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
  * frame #12: 0x000000010a53f7f7 PlannerTab`main at AppDelegate.swift:12
    frame #13: 0x000000010f955d81 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Comment: Is there no additional indication of at what line the issue is in Xcode ?

Comment: The "SIGBART" error brings up the AppDelegate.swift file and points to the definition of the App Delegate Class.

Comment: Where is clicked cell being set?

Comment: It's being set at the top of ViewController.swift, but modified whenever a cell is clicked to be the indexPath.row for that cell.

Comment: You can try using the "Exception Breakpoint..." option under "Show breakpoing navigator" in left pane of XCode workspace for debugging at which line the exact issue causes. This may help you find the cause of the issue. Try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing/commenting this line fixed your crash

classPicker.selectRow(1, inComponent: 1, animated: false)

basically you have only 1 component, so the correct line for you would be

classPicker.selectRow(1, inComponent: 0, animated: false)

Comment: Wow, debugging for hours and you manage to find this! Thank you! I didn't realize that the Components started at 0.